# ffmpeg filter to add timestamp on video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, timestamp, timer

I have a problem displaying the timer on the video. I have consulted a few examples, but it does not show success. Help me fix it.

[image]

Comment: Copy and paste your ffmpeg command into your question so we can try it ourselves.

Comment: You can see the image I have attached to the above

Comment: Yes, but I could not copy and paste your command to easily debug it, and there are too many other questions to answer for me to look at the image and re-type it.

Answer (score 4):

try this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=roboto.ttf:fontsize=36:fontcolor=yellow:text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1575526882\:%A, %d, %B %Y %I\\\:%M\\\:%S %p}'" -preset ultrafast -f mp4 output.mp4
```

made changes in command as per your need.

also refer below links it will give you more idea about timestamp:

[strftime - format date and time](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)

Comment: I get this error: `[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x55dfb2a1c4c0] Stray % near 'S %p}'` when I try to run this, on ffmpeg version `4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1`

Answer (score 2):

I use the following filter:

`-vf drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMonoBold.ttf:text='%{localtime}':fontcolor=white@0.8:x=7:y=7`

I put this filter between the input specifications and the output specifications.

You just have to adapt:

- `x=XX` and `y=YY` depending on the wished position.
- `fontfile=` depending on the fonts available on your system.

Comment: I tried but having trouble displaying. they don't show the time, they are just characters.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly for me on the first try. I removed the "fontfile=/...ttf" part completely and it used a default font. Adding :fontsize=24 before :fontcolor made it bigger, too.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post from google trying to overlay time elapsed for my video. Learned that the proper term for it is [Burnt-in timecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnt-in_timecode), and found a post that was [close](https://superuser.com/a/1613753/1320270). Made some changes and was able to get the timecode burn in for my video in the bottom right corner in yellow:

```
 ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontsize=60:fontcolor=yellow:text='%{pts\:hms}':x=(w-text_w):y=(h-text_h)" output.mp4
```

[image]